# DIV Layout in HTML/ASPX

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to develop a ASPX UI with following DIV layout. Can anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: Did you read some tutorials? Did you try something already? Did you encounter some specific difficulties with your code? Right now you haven't really asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

well it's a CSS/HTML code,hope it guides you : [AN EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0e0b5L2d/)

```
<div class="l"></div>
<div class="r">
    <div class="tr"></div>
    <div class="tl"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use inline css with aspx

```
<div id="div1" style="border:double;width:10%;height:100%;float:left">
     <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
<div id="div2" style="border:double;width:10%;height:50%;margin-left:12%;margin-top:0%;">
    <br /><br /><br />
</div>
<div id="div3" style="border:double;width:10%;height:50%;margin-left:13%;margin-top:-12%;float:left">
    <br /><br /><br />
 </div>
 <div id="div4" style="border:double;margin-left:12%;margin-top:2%;width:22%;">
    <br /><br /><br />
 </div>
```